# property of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$. I want to prove that if $J$ and $K$ are left ideals of $R$ such that $JK\subseteq P$, then either $J\subseteq P$ or $K\subseteq P$.

I think I want to try something along the lines of considering the set of all $r\in R$ such that $rK \subseteq P$ and show that this set is an ideal containing $J$, but I don't know if this is the right way to go. Could someone help me see how to finish the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an easy solution from your start. I would assume otherwise. So if $J\not\subset P$ and $K\not\subset P$ then there exists $a\in J$ and $b\in K$ such that $ab\in P$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: I think so. If $ab\in P$, then since $P$ is prime, either $a\in P$ or $b\in P$, so the claim follows. Wow, that was easy!

Comment: However, why can you say for sure that since $J$ and $K$ are not contained in $P$, then there exists an $a\in J$ and a $b\in K$ such that $ab \in P$?

Comment: What does it mean for a set to be a subset of another?

Comment: Sorry, sorry. I forgot that $JK\subseteq P$ was an assumption. I'm running on few hours of sleep.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was not so wildly far away from a good one:

Suppose $\;K\rlap{\,/}{\subset}\, P\;\implies\;\exists\;k\in K\;\;s.t.\;\;k\notin P$ , but then we have that

$$\forall\,j\in J\;,\;\;jk\in P\implies j\in P\;(\text{since}\;\;k\notin P)\implies J\subset P$$